# Different strategies for persistent container-data in docker

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Basically I've seen four different ways of managing data in docker containers

1. Using the "ephemeral" volume inside the container - data is deleted when container is removed
2. Mapping a container on the host to a volume in the docker container - only recommended for testing purposes
3. Creating a "data-container" and mapping that containers volume to other containers
4. Creating a docker "data-volume" and mapping that to other containers

As far as I understood, alternative 3 and 4 is the most recommended approaches, but I'm wondering what the advantages/disadvantages to the different approaches are?

Some code to illustrate what I'm meaning:

**Data container**

Explained here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container

```
docker create -v /dbdata --name dbstore training/postgres /bin/true
docker run -d --volumes-from dbstore --name db1 training/postgres
```

**Data volume**

Explained here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Using different "docker volume" commands to maintain the volumes

```
docker volume create --name hello
docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world
```

**Usecase**

To run jira, bitbucket, jenkins, sonar and nexus as docker containers with the possibility to backup application data as simple and reliable as possible :-)

Comment: There are docker volume plugins that give you more options: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins/

Comment: It really depends on your use case, and at least #3 is no longer a primary reco in recent versions of Docker, see: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20465

Comment: Thanks ldg! Actually looks like the documentation is deprecated after the "docker volume" commands were introduced.

Comment: we are using option 4 for several months and didn't have issues. We create daily backups of our volumes and export the .tars to S3